# Grails testing a failing domain save in service

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I've a Grails (3+) service where a domain object is retrieved from the DB, modified , and then updated in the DB.

```
class MyService {
    def modifyObject(String uuid) {
        def md = MyDomain.findByUuid(uuid)
        md.someField = true
        if (!md.save()){ 
            throw new MyException()
        }
    }
}
```

Now **I need to test this service method with a negative test**, to be sure that the exception is thrown. But I can't figure out how to *force* a failing `save` in the service method.

```
@TestFor(MyService)
@Mock(MyDomain)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "test An exceptionl situation was found"() {
        given: "An uuid"
            def md = new MyDomain(uuid: "123")
            md.save(failOnError: true)

        when: "service is called"
            service.modifyObject("123")

        then: "An exception is thrown"
            thrown MyException
    }
}
```

Obviously, re-defining the service method in a more functional way (the object is passed directly to the method, modified and returned *without save* .e.g `MyDomain modifyObject(MyDomain md)`) will be a good solution since I could create an invalid *ad hoc* object outside or even invalidate it after the method execution.

But the question is: "**is there a way to test the service code *as is*?**"

Comment: Violate a constraint on MyDomain and the save should fail, no?
If the modifyObject is really that simple (you can't pass in a bogus value to force a constraint violation), maybe you need to metaClass the MyDomain.save and force a failure there.

Comment: @railsdog if you provide a complete working answer i could accept it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really do want to throw an exception and not just handle validation errors, then sure. You'll want to utilize Spock's support for interaction based testing and leverage static method stubs. See similar question, [Unit test grails with domain objects using GORM functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017991/unit-test-grails-with-domain-objects-using-gorm-functions/35029941#35029941).

You need some way to isolate the service method and stub out the GORM functionality. This can be tricky with static methods, but can be accomplished with a global GroovyMock or [GroovySpy](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_mocking_static_methods). In essence, you're replacing all instances/references to `MyDomain` for the duration of the method (though the GroovySpy will fall back on the actual domain class unless an interaction matches).

With the Mock/Spy in place, you can specify the interactions you expect to occur and specify what those interactions should return. In this case, we expect the `findByUuid` to be invoked with an argument of `"123"` once, and we return a mock `MyDomain` object. That mock object then has it's `save()` method invoked once where we return null, i.e. the save failed.

```
void "test An exceptional situation was found"() {
    setup:
        GroovySpy(MyDomain, global: true)
        def mockDomain = Mock(MyDomain)

    when: "service is called"
        service.modifyObject("123")

    then: "An exception is thrown"
        1 * MyDomain.findByUuid("123") >> mockDomain
        1 * mockDomain.save() >> null
        thrown Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you violate a constraint on MyDomain and the save should fail, no?

If the modifyObject is really that simple, and you can't pass in a bogus value to force a constraint violation, maybe you need to metaClass the MyDomain.save and force a failure there.